# The last if statement will not be executed when the conditions of the list are met?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game noughts and crosses")

    While game = 1
        While gameplay = 0
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a square to place X")
        move = Console.ReadLine

        If row(move - 1) = " " Then
                row(move - 1) = row(move - 1).Replace(CChar(" "), CChar("X"))
                gameplay = 1
            count = count + 1
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("That space has already been taken")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(row(0) & row(1) & row(2))
        Console.WriteLine(row(3) & row(4) & row(5))
        Console.WriteLine(row(6) & row(7) & row(8))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    While gameplay = 1
            npcmove = (10 * Rnd())

            If row(npcmove - 1) = " " Then
                row(npcmove - 1) = row(npcmove - 1).Replace(CChar(" "), CChar("O"))
                gameplay = 0
                count = count + 1
                Console.WriteLine("The CPU has chosen to place O in space " & npcmove)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("That space has already been taken")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(row(0) & row(1) & row(2))
        Console.WriteLine(row(3) & row(4) & row(5))
        Console.WriteLine(row(6) & row(7) & row(8))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End While
    End While
End Sub

Sub endgame()
    If count = 9 Then
        Console.WriteLine("The game was a tie")
        Console.ReadLine()
        FileClose()

    End If
End Sub

Sub VicRoy()
    If (row(0).Contains("X") & row(1).Contains("X") & row(2).Contains("X")) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations on the epic Victory Royale")
        Console.ReadLine()
        FileClose() 

    End If
```

The code runs a noughts and crosses game with a random ai using while loops. The board is represented via a new list of strings. However once I meet the condition of the if statement, where all the values are X the if statement will not be executed and the game will continue

Comment: I'm not sure you asked a question, but you talk about "the if statement" like there is only one, yet there seem to be several.. please clarify

Comment: Sorry about tjhat, I now realise that the question is poorly formatted.  The if statement that isnt working is the last one which will be excecuted when those 3 values of the list will be met but when they are the if statement isnt excecuted,

Comment: So, one wins only if it places X in the first row? That doesn't seems to be the rules that I remember

Comment: yeah i have the other combinations as well but i only copied 1 as the format is essentially the same

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime. Fix the problems it points out. This should always be on in all your projects.

Answer (score 1):

replace & with And, the & in vb.net mean you just will Merage strings